# Magento 2.4.5 recaptcha issue when move discount form to before methods

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, magento2.4.5, recaptcha

In checkout i moved "Apply Discount Code" form from afterMethods to beforeMethods.

After upgrade to 2.4.5 recaptcha was added to this form.

But doesnt load correctly

```
<div data-bind="{
    attr: {
        'id': getReCaptchaId() + '-wrapper'
    },
    'afterRender': renderReCaptcha()
}" id="recaptcha-checkout-coupon-apply-wrapper">
    <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
    <!-- ko if: (!getIsInvisibleRecaptcha()) -->
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" class="required-captcha checkbox" name="recaptcha-validate-" data-validate="{required:true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

This happen even when is disabled.

If I left the form in afterMethods works correctly.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The ReCaptchaCheckoutSalesRule module adds a new layoutProcessor.

In my code the form was moved using a plugin on the file Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor

In this way the form was moved before the recaptcha was configured using the function:

```
public function process($jsLayout)
{
    $key = 'coupon_code';
    if ($this->isCaptchaEnabled->isCaptchaEnabledFor($key)) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
        ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['discount']['children']
        ['checkout_sales_rule']['settings'] = $this->captchaUiConfigResolver->get($key);
    } else {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['discount']['children']['checkout_sales_rule'])) {
            unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['discount']['children']['checkout_sales_rule']);
        }
    }

    return $jsLayout;
}
```

in Magento\ReCaptchaCheckoutSalesRule\Block\LayoutProcessor\Checkout\Onepage

So I had to create a new plugin for the latter file and move the code from the previous plugin to the new one

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout;
class MoveDiscountForm
{
    protected $logger;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\ReCaptchaCheckoutSalesRule\Block\LayoutProcessor\Checkout\Onepage $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {     
        //move discount to beforeMethods

        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['discount'])) {
            
            $discountFormBefore = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
            ['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']
            ['beforeMethods']['children']['discount'];
            
            $discountFormBefore = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['discount'];
             
            unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
            ['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']
            ['children']['afterMethods']['children']['discount']);
        }
        
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```